# Creating Image from Coordinates to Scale

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to create an image based off of x and y coordinates with the line thickness to scale (in mm). Ultimately the image will be used to check against for defects. To visualize the concept, think of x/y coordinates of a PCB traces, where the thickness of the line is critical.

I have researched the topic and found applications that use actual pictures of the PCB to compare against, however I need to "virtually" create the images as they are being created at very low quantities but extremely high quality.

This article does a good job of show the entire process. Click https://www.electroschematics.com/pcb-defects-detection-opencv/

I have also researched stack overflow and not found any similar issues.

I have tried basic methods using matplotlib, which is easy to assign a width, however there is no way to know what it is in terms of scale.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
y = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I have no way of guaranteeing that line width = 1 means its 1 mm thick. Similarly for comparison purposes, I do not know ow to make the image to scale in terms of pixels of the actual inspection camera pixels.

Ideally, I would be able to plot the x/y coordinates from the original design file, assign the proper width to the path with correct scale, then use Open CV to compare the expected design file against actual camera pictures to detect flaws.

Comment: Your link is bad. It says 404 error. What thickness value do you need? Is the line thickness constant or does it vary with x,y location?

Comment: the link works for me fine when i use it. If you google "PCB Defects Detection with OpenCV" it is the first result. The line thickness will be constant throughout the image, however it may change from one design to the next. Current test value is 0.8mm.

Comment: The CSS standard is 96 pixels per inch. So convert your 0.8mm to pixels using that conversion. 96*0.8/25.4=3.2px. See https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/understanding-css-units/